# Created website using Django, but the images are not showing when deployed to heroku but shows in localhost

Tags: python, django, image, heroku, deployment

The images are coming from the table in where the admin have uploaded the images:

[image: First webpage]

These is my settings to store static files and media:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portfolio/static/')

 ]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

The models I've created:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

class Job(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length= 200)

class Project(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.title)

class Social(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.title)

class Skills(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.title)
```

In templates I have:

```
 <img src="{{profile_pic.image.url}}" height="600px" width="500x" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail"
            alt="Responsive image">
          <br>
```

In views I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Job, Skills, Project, Social, ProfileImage

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.all()
    skills = Skills.objects.all()
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    socials = Social.objects.all()
    profile_pic = ProfileImage.objects.all().first()
    context = {'jobs':jobs, 'skills':skills, 'projects':projects, 'socials':socials, 'profile_pic':profile_pic}
    return render(request, 'jobs/home.html', context)
```

When I deploy to heroku it shows:

[image: Second Webpage]

Answer (score 0):

how are you serving the static files? There's [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) you can use that or other services like google cloud or aws to serve the static files on production.

Here's what Heroku had on their dev center as to how to serve static files in production. [Serve static files on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

Comment: i am new to deploying to heroku can and do not know much about whitenoise. Can u explain how can i use whitenoise? Thank you

Comment: it's actually quite simple to do so! and Heroku has a step by step as to how to configure whitenoise on Heroku in production, so I'd try to follow this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets and see if you can accomplish your goal.

Comment: actually i am uploading the images from the admin panel and "/app/media/images/flask.jpg" does not exist this shows when i click on the image inside the admin panel. I've searched for answers and found that the images should be stored in S3 sever. Is there a alternative for S3 which does not require any credit card details?

Comment: That's what I know as well too. You'd have to save them in s3 and then you'll be able to use them in production.

you know I am still learning trying to really understand the whole static files serving in production. 

I am afraid that I can't point you in any other direction, where the credit card info isn't required. Look into the digital ocean or google cloud! Good luck.

if you find any way to get it done please let me know.